# Smarty Conditionals

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to use smarty code to print an opponent's name when one is set, but when the name isn't set, I want to just display "Someone".

```
{if isset($OPPONENT_FULL_NAME)}
    %%OPPONENT_FULL_NAME%% 
{else} 
    Someone 
{/if} started a game with you.
```

Right now when I set `$OPPONENT_FULL_NAME` to something it works well, but when I leave it blank nothing shows up. No "Someone".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$OPPONENT_FULL_NAME` may be set, but to a blank string.  You might try doing something like

```
{if isset($OPPONENT_FULL_NAME) && $OPPONENT_FULL_NAME not '' }%%OPPONENT_FULL_NAME%% {else} Someone {/if} started a game with you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that null is different of empty String

```
{if !isset($OPPONENT_FULL_NAME) || $OPPONENT_FULL_NAME eq ''}
   {$OPPONENT_FULL_NAME}
{else}
   Someone
{/if|
```

Comment: This is effectively the same as @bhamby's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the filtering, sanitization, or conditioning in php first. 
For example:
 `$OPPONENT_FULL_NAME = (isset($OPPONENT_FULL_NAME) AND !empty($OPPONENT_FULL_NAME)) ? $OPPONENT_FULL_NAME : "Someone";`
Then, you can just call `{$OPPONENT_FULL_NAME}` in smarty template.

However, if you have to do it in smarty template, 
 
`{$OPPONENT_FULL_NAME|default: "Someone"}` will do the trick.

Hope that help, cheers!

Comment: You should always explain your answer, otherwise it may get deleted.